# NA/NaN argument Error in creating json in R

Tags: r

I want to query data from elastic search in R.

```
library(elasticsearch)
query <- query('{"match": {"drv_age" : 63}}')
data <- elastic("http://localhost:9200", "acturial", "data") %search% query
```

It works fine, but I want to do this in the following way because I am setting parameters from command line.

```
index.name <- "acturial"
index.type <- "data"  
col.name <- "drv_age"  
value <- "63"  
query <- query({"match": {col.name : value}}) 
data <- elastic("http://localhost:9200", index.name, index.type) %search% query
```

It gives me the following error

> Error in col.name:value : NA/NaN argument

Comment: You'll need to create your query string using `paste0( )`. For example, `qry <- paste0('{ "match" : {"', col.name, '" : ', value , '} } ')`, and then use this inside `query(qry) `

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a string from objects in R you need to use a function like `paste0()`

For example,

```
qry <- paste0('{ "match" : {"', col.name, '" : ', value , '} } '),
```

will give you your query string, and then use this inside query as

```
query <- query(qry)
```

Comment: ... or you could use [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) (e.g., `as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(list(match=setNames(list(val), nm=cn))))`), so you don't have to worry about escaping, quotes, etc.